# How to set a parameter for a method that returns a number in a servlet and pass it to jsp file?

Tags: jsp, servlets, set

I am a complete beginner to java web applications and I'm trying to design a page to show the total pay for an ArrayList. I have a method in my Service class that returns a double from an ArrayList:

```
public double totalPayroll(String name) {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < payrollList.size(); i++) {
        total += payrollList.get(i).calWage();
    }
    return total;
}
```

On my servlet, I want to add a request to the doGet method in a Servlet for this method so that I can display the total on my jsp file. On the Servlet file, I have tried:

request.setAttribute("productList", service.totalPayroll());

and tried the following for the jsp file:

```
"<h3>Total Payroll to Pay: </h3><c:out value="$${payroll.totalPayroll()}" />"
```

but I am getting an error that method is not applicable for the argument. It seems that I need to set the attribute to match the return value of the method but I cannot figure out how to do that on the Servlet and how to call it on the jsp file. I appreciate any help or guidance on how to solve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error that you see? Which exception class & message for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Question the question isn't clear but still i would like give an solution based on my understanding of question

Try This:

On Servlet

```
         double totalPayroll=00;
        totalPayroll=service.totalPayroll("parameterValue"); //You have to send parameter/argument as your method defination requires 1 parameter/argument 
        request.setAttribute("Demo", totalPayroll);
        RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("yourjspfile.jsp"); //Enter the name of your jsp file
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

on Jsp:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored = "false" %> //top of the page
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  //top of the page &add jstl jar to your project
  Total Payroll to Pay: <c:out value="${Demo}"/> You can add condition for its visiblity.
```

Comment: Cheers!If  this helped you,you can accept it as a Right answer.